# Interswitch payment Gateway Integration using ionic and cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, payment-gateway

I have developed a mobile app using ionic framework and `cordova`. In my backend mysql. and storing data using `php` code. Any way to integrate `Interswitch` payment Gateway using ionic and `cordova` or any other for hybrid mobile app.

Comment: Did you find any solution?